# TypeScript: sort array of objects by variabke key where key might be optional

Tags: typescript

i have an Type and an Array of Objects of this Type. "Unfortunally" some keys in that Type are optional. That breaks my dynamic sort function. How can I make this work? I won't call it with those optional keys so it would be OK if the function does not or does wrongly sort in that case.

```
export type Test = {
  adam: string;
  eve?: string;
};

export type Container = {
  test: Array<Test>;
};

const testContainer = {} as Container;
export function sortTest(prop: keyof Test) {
  testContainer.test.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a[prop] === undefined || b[prop] === undefined || !(prop in b) || !(prop in a)) {
      return 0;
    } else {
      return a[prop] > b[prop] ? -1 : b[prop] > a[prop] ? 1 : 0;
    }
  });
}
```

As you can see, i tried 2 different approaches to make sure `prop` is part of `a` and `b`. Both don't work. I'm always getting ts 2532 - Object is possibly 'undefined' at the actual sorting line.

Link to [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAqwDO8C8cDeAsAFBxwCGAJuQLYBcc2UAlgHYDmA3CWcAG7AA-AyZsuJAL7diJUJFgJkqAMIRWMcm2BQ4eIqQRYYDAIJQo5RAB4M2AHzSpJEgGM12Q9lXrNrbboIJCkw4bw0tKGk5aHgAMwBXVhcYZjVGGNsYAAowKAgwBgBrYEQIWPQjAEoCHk8YMN9tADoYIybMGKys8gAaOAAjapw7GoMyZnLugG1c-IBdXRw8RMpgWK1KOAAfLYGZvLAFpeXWVfW-TZ24AEIcg7g2Aeqr29mwB9YKSur9Mj+4KDAGDxKCfAAM0n+QWAABtMKhfv8AUCQZ9yPt5nARv0MYc4II4ABaACMcAYOLeCxG6Mp+LgpIYENqZAktQklUcJCAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save `a[prop]` and `b[prop]` into variables:

```
testContainer.test.sort((a, b) => {
  const aProp = a[prop];
  const bProp = b[prop];
  if (aProp === undefined || bProp === undefined) return 0;
  return aProp > bProp ? -1 : bProp > aProp? 1 : 0;
});
```

From [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48335#issuecomment-1073052038):

> This isn't really about TS2532 specifically but about type narrowing
> in general--TS doesn't treat any check involving `obj[key]` as a type
> guard unless `key` is a literal.